# How to load and preprocess a dataset by chunks?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, nlp

I have a large data frame to which I would like to apply a set of functions to one of its columns using `pipeline` and `progress_apply()`.

Here is my code snippet.

```py
df = # a dataFrame object with multiple columns where df.columns[-1] == 'text' 
from tqdm.auto import tqdm
tqdm.pandas()

pipeline = # list of pre-defined methods
prepare(text, pipeline):
   """
   a method that cleanup and remove stop words from text input
   """
   return # list of clean tokens

# MemoryError! when reaching 50% of cleaning progress
df = df['text'].progress_apply(prepare, pipeline=pipeline)
```

I am trying to solve the issue of `MemoryError` using `progress_apply()` but loading data by **chunks**. I have no idea of how I can do this with `progress_apply()`.
I tried the following:

```py
for i in range(0, df.shape[0], 47):
   df = df['text'][i:i+47].progress_apply(prepare, pipeline=pipeline)
```

What I have tried doesn't same the previous ranges.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
n, step = df.shape[0], 47
for i in range(0, n, step):
   df[i:i+step] = df['text'][i:i+step].progress_apply(prepare, pipeline=pipeline)
```