# How to slice a list based on its elements?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have the following list

```py
lst = [i for i in range(0, 1974, 47)]
```

I would like to slice it in a way to have: `(0, 564)`, `(564, 846)`, `(846, 1128)`, `(1128, 1410)`, `(1410, 1692)`, and `(1692, 1927)`.

I tried the following:

```py
print(lst[0], lst[6*2])
for i in range(2, 7):
    print(lst[6*i], lst[6*i+1])
```

I am expecting to hard code the first tuple and last one inside the for loop.

I tried manually the following:

```py
h = [i for i in range(0, 1974, 47)]
print(h[0], h[6*2])
print(h[6*2], h[6*3])
print(h[6*3], h[6*4])
print(h[6*4], h[6*5])
print(h[6*5], h[6*6])
print(h[6*6], h[6*6+5])
```

Comment: Do you really want to slice? Or to generate the list of tuples from scratch?

Comment: I want to slice. I tried this `[(h[6*i], h[6*(i+2)]) for i in range(0, 6, 2)]` which still miss the last tuple `(1692, 1927)`

Comment: Your question is really unclear regarding what is the input (and how this eventually generalizes) and what is the output.

Comment: I want to find a slicer pattern to output a list of tuples mentioned in the question.

Comment: "I want to slice" In your own words, what do you think it actually means to slice a list? Because neither your code, *nor your expected output*, shows any kind of slicing. Also: "I tried the following:" Please say, **in the question itself**: what happened when you tried that? **How is that different** from what is supposed to happen?

Comment: I provided a last attempt. This is only printing like your original code but it is trivial to make tuples instead. If this is not what you want, I think you should really think how to rework the question to improve clarity

Comment: The aim of this question is to attempt this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/71402907/10543310

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To generate your list of tuples, you could use:

```
up = 1927
step = 282
out = [(i*step, min(up, (i+1)*step))
       for i in range(2, up//step+1)]
```

Output:

```
[(564, 846), (846, 1128), (1128, 1410), (1410, 1692), (1692, 1927)]
```

To *index* your list to produce the shown pattern you could use:

```
for i in range(1, len(lst)//6):
    a = 0 if i == 1 else 6*i
    b = min(6*(i+1), len(lst)-1)
    print(lst[a], lst[b])
```

Output:

```
0 564
564 846
846 1128
1128 1410
1410 1692
1692 1927
```

Comment: Thank you, @mozaway. What I want to have as output is just tuples instead of list ranges.

Comment: @Joe the logic is not fully clear, but check the update